# Как сделать чтобы текст в QLineEdit умещался весь?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qlineedit

Проблема такая: в QLineEdit при введении длинного текста, он сдвигается влево. А как можно сделать, чтобы QLineEdit сама увеличилась если текст слишком длинный.

Comment: И допустим у меня этот QLineEdit появляется по нажатии кнопки. И как мне сделать так, чтобы на ней появился сразу курсор для ввода?

Comment: Чтобы курсор появлялся вызовите у line_edit setFocus()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e0b009939348617a0b17d4c6c51ed13884a1f5a6/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/autowidth__QLineEdit.py) увеличения минимальной ширины `QLineEdit` при вводе текста.

Ловим сигнал `textChanged`, в слоте рассчитываем длину текста и меняем ширину у виджета:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.line_edit = Qt.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def on_text_changed(self, text):
        # Рассчитываем ширину текст по шрифту
        width = self.line_edit.fontMetrics().width(text)
        self.line_edit.setMinimumWidth(width)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = Widget()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Супер! Огромное спасибо. И если можно еще один вопрос, а можно ли ограничить количество вводимых символов в QLineEdit?

Comment: Можно вызвать `setMaxLength()` или настроить маску ввода. [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо)